# Impossible to restore PostgreSQL database from dump

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My computer runs Ubuntu 14.04 with postgreSQL 9.3

I would like to restore a large PSQL database called bigdb on my computer from a dump file (dump file size = 2.3GB).

The dump file comes from a different computer, I currently don't have any prior version of the database on my computer.

I created an empty database called testdb in which I'd like to "write" bigdb

I tried the command:

```
$pg_restore -C -d testdb dump.dmp
```

It gave me around 300 errors of this type:

> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 15475; 0 25342 TABLE DATA tb_italmaj jturf
>   pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "tb_italmaj" does not exist
>       Command was: COPY tb_italmaj (id_mvtmaj, file_name, file_dh, pgdone, pgdonedh, pgfonctrue, pgerrcode, pgerrmess, pgrowdata) FROM stdin;

At the end, testdb is still empty.
It seems like testdb needs to have the same "structure" (tables,...) as bigdb, but I thought the parameter "-C" would create the database.

I also tried to extract the dump in a plain txt file dump.sql and I tried restoring it with the command:

```
$psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 testdb < dump.sql
```

This error popped out immediately:

> ERROR: relation "id_tab_eed__texte_seq" does not exist

Likewise it seems that the relations from bigdb need to be created before restoring it and I can't do this.

The only command that executed properly was:

```
$pg_restore -C dump.dmp
```

But in this case, no database was created on my computer.

I have been struggling with this issue for several hours. Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

PS: This is my first post and I am not a native english speaker, I hope I was clear. If not, feel free to ask for complementary information.

Comment: And you are connecting to the database as user=postgres ? Are you allowed to create databases, schemas,tables, etc?

Comment: Could you have done a --data-only dump? Look at the start of the dump file, are there CREATE TABLE commands etc early on? (For future reference btw, prefer `pg_dump -Fc` as much as possible)

Comment: @joop : Yes I am connecting as user=postgres

Comment: @CraigRinger: Unfortunately I don't know how the dump was created. The plain text sql file has a size of 13GB so I am not sure how can I open it without crashing my computer.

Comment: @mpicard A decent text editor will handle it fine. try notdepad++, I  think it should. Or use the "more" command from cmd.exe